# Getting jquery UI sortable to work, one part I don't understand

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable

The part I don't understand in the code below is "function(serialized)". I know change means when the change event has occured run the positions() function but I don't see what function(serialized) signifies?

```
$('#col').Sortable(
                {
                    accept: 'widget',
                    opacity: 0.5,
                    helperclass: 'helper',
                    change: function(serialized) { positions(); },
                    handle: '.titlebar'
                }
            );
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`function(serialized) { positions(); }` the anonymous function is called on change and the var serialized will contain the data. It is most likely called "serialized" as that is how the data will be structured. You could change that to `function(great_bit_of_data) { positions(); }`
 and it should still work as there's nothing in the function using the var.

Comment: Just one thing, by the 'anonymous function', you mean the 'positions()' function? If so, I understand. Thanks.

Comment: No, the anonymous function is `function(serialized) {  }`. Basically the function gets created and called on `change`, once that function gets called it calls another function called `positions();`. Without being able to see the `positions();` function I can only guess as the why it's called.

Comment: You could also try updating the following from this `change: function(serialized) { positions(); }` to this `change: positions` which should call the `positions()` function directly.